# Regex : Strip off HTML tags from sting but leave email address in '<>'

Tags: regex

I looked into many StackOverflow questions but none of them answer my question.

Basically, I could have a string like below:

```
"From: 'Hima Chitalia (Hima- at Web Development)' via IWeb Development Support [mailto:hima@webdevelopement.com] 
<div>Sent: Monday, January 7, 2019 7:24 PM
</div><div>To: Hima Chhag (hc) <hchhag@wd.com>;
</div><div>Cc: Hima (hagain) <hagain@web.com>;
</div><div>Subject: RE: strip off HTML Tags but not email addresses
</div><div><br></div>"
```

So, If there are any HTML tags, I need to replace it with an empty string. But if there is an email address like this '<hchhag@wd.com>'. It should be left as it is.

Few things I tried:

```
string.replace(/<[^<>]*>/g,'')
string.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,'')
string.replace(/<(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>/g,'')
```

**Actual Result:**

```
 "From: 'Hima Chitalia (Hima- at Web Development)' via Web Development Support [mailto:hima@webdevelopement.com] 
Sent: Monday, January 7, 2019 7:24 PM
To: Hima Chhag (hc) ; 
Cc: Hima (hagain) 
Subject: RE: strip off HTML Tags but not email addresses
"
```

**Expected:**

```
 "From: 'Hima Chitalia (Hima- at Web Development)' via Web Development Support [mailto:hima@webdevelopement.com] 
Sent: Monday, January 7, 2019 7:24 PM
To: Hima Chhag (hc) <hchhag@wd.com>; 
Cc: Hima (hagain) <hagain@web.com>
Subject: RE: strip off HTML Tags but not email addresses
"
```

Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: Use an HTML parser to extract the contents because [you can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Comment: @Richardissimo is right. The answer I gave is based on the case you showed and assume there is no other `<>` marks than the tags ones.

Comment: @Richardissimo. Thanks a lot for the link to understand the problem in a broader sense. It worked like an eye-opener for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you would just need to check tag names without a `@`:

```
string.replace(/<[^@>]+>/g,'')
```